# How to get value prediction from Polynomial curve?

Tags: math

Okay, so maths isn't my strong point!

I have this data, I i used zunzun.com to create a User Defined Polynomial curve for my data, which came out as `y = a + bx1 + cx2 + dx3 + ex4 + fx5`

However, when I use the code suggested:

```
  double a = -4.2294409347240979E+01;
  double b = 5.5946102161174718E+00;
  double c = -1.3446057748924720E-01;
  double d = 1.5448461146899649E-03;
  double e = -8.2537158069276241E-06;
  double f = 1.7176546321558128E-08;

  temp = f;
  temp = temp * x_in + e;
  temp = temp * x_in + d;
  temp = temp * x_in + c;
  temp = temp * x_in + b;
  temp = temp * x_in + a;
  return temp;
```

It gives me the 'sum of squared absolute error'? Say for X value 94, I should get a value of about 60.3, but this code gives me -46.152. I realise I am being stupid and am obviously missing an equation on the end. But can anyone help me predict my Y value from my X with this forumla? The graph fits its really well and would be great to not have to use a lookup table.

Many Thanks!

> X Y
>   180 200
>   178 190
>   176 180
>   174 170
>   170 160
>   168 150
>   164 140
>   160 130
>   154 120
>   149 110
>   142 100
>   134 90
>   122 80
>   110 70
>   92 60
>   66 50
>   30 40

**Thanks everyone! Code is working now:** http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/3705/ps3lrftest.png

Comment: When I enter your data into http://zunzun.com/Equation/2/Polynomial/User-Selectable%20Polynomial/ it offers me a *quadratic*, which is in line with what I would expect from the graph. Is that the page you used?

Comment: Seems to me that the code you were given is correct.  I think your problem is that whatever the data type of temp is you are losing a level of precision.  Is temp a double or a float? Is the x_in value a double or possibly an Int

Comment: Yes AkashM I used that page - I'm useless when it comes to maths, I got excited when I found a curve that fit. Do you have a better less processor intensive way of doing the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse my rounding but you're implementing;

Y = a + b*x + c*x^2 + d*x^3 + e*x^4 + f*x^5

x = 94
x^2 == x*x = 8836

x^3 == x*x*x = 830584

x^4 == x*x*x*x = 78074896
x^5 == x*x*x*x*x = 7339040224

A ~ -42.29440934
B ~  05.59461021
C ~ -0.134460577
D ~  0.001544846
E ~ -0.000008253
F ~  0.000000017

Y = -42.29440934 + 05.59461021*94 + -0.134460577*8836 + 0.001544846*830584 + -0.000008253*78074896 + 0.000000017*7339040224

Y = -42.29440934 + 525.89335974 - 1188.093658372 + 1283.124370064 - 644.352116688 + 124.763683808

Y = 59.041229212

Not quite your answer but with sufficient accuracy you should be good.

Comment: Thank you dave I understood your answer best. Your right I just copied the code, once I understood what was I happening I sorted it :)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever temp computes, it's not the y value. But you've figured out as much :)
This should do?

```
def y(x, coefficients):
    result = 0
    xpower = 1    
    for coeff in coefficients:
        result += xpower*coeff
        xpower *= x    
    return result
```

Comment: whoops. wrong language. but do you get the basic idea? everytime you loop: a) get the current coefficient b) multiply it with the current power of x c) multiply current power of x with itself

Comment: In order to make this compute you would a would have to be the last coefficient in the coefficient array passed in.

Comment: um, no. a is the linear term..? y = a + bx1 + cx2 + dx3 + ex4 + fx5

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with your implementation, but the code you gave is correct. You can write (using second degree polynomial for simplicity):

```
y = a + b*x + c*x^2
```

as

```
y = a + (b + (c)*x)*x
```

or, equivalently:

```
temp = c
temp = temp*x + b
temp = temp*x + a
y = temp
```

You just assign the expression inside the parenthesis to temp from the innermost one and expanding outwards.

This is the same format that you've shown above. Just use 6 coefficients instead of 3. For more details on this polynomial evaluation method, you can read [Horner's Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme) in Wikipedia.

To validate, using Python:

```
>>> a = -4.2294409347240979E+01
>>> b = 5.5946102161174718E+00
>>> c = -1.3446057748924720E-01
>>> d = 1.5448461146899649E-03
>>> e = -8.2537158069276241E-06
>>> f = 1.7176546321558128E-08
>>> def test(x):
...     t = f
...     t = t*x + e
...     t = t*x + d
...     t = t*x + c
...     t = t*x + b
...     t = t*x + a
...     return t
...
>>> test(94)
60.281114720346885
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd write it in Java:

```
/**
 * Polynomial
 * User: Michael
 * Date: Jul 27, 2010
 * Time: 7:15:41 PM
 */
public class Polynomial
{
    private double [] coeff;

    public Polynomial(double[] coeff)
    {
        if ((coeff == null) || (coeff.length == 0))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("coefficient array cannot be null or empty");

        this.coeff = new double [coeff.length];
        System.arraycopy(coeff, 0, this.coeff, 0, coeff.length);
    }

    public double eval(double x)
    {
        int numTerms = coeff.length;
        double value = coeff[numTerms-1];

        for (int i = (numTerms-2); i >= 0; --i)
        {
            value += value*x + this.coeff[i];
        }

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(128);

        for (int i = 0; i < (this.coeff.length-1); ++i)
        {
            builder.append("a[").append(i).append("]=").append(this.coeff[i]).append(",");
        }

        builder.append("a[").append(this.coeff.length-1).append("]=").append(this.coeff[this.coeff.length-1]);

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Here's how I'd test it:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

/**
 * PolynomialTest
 * User: Michael
 * Date: Jul 27, 2010
 * Time: 7:26:15 PM
 */
public class PolynomialTest
{
    private static final double [] a =
    {
        -4.2294409347240979E+01,
         5.5946102161174718E+00,
        -1.3446057748924720E-01,
         1.5448461146899649E-03,
        -8.2537158069276241E-06,
         1.7176546321558128E-08,
    };

    private Polynomial p = new Polynomial(a);

    @Test
    public void testEval()
    {
        double x = 94.0;
        double expected = 60.83781703621137;
        double actual = p.eval(x);

        assertEquals(expected, actual, 1.0e-3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testToString()
    {
        String expected = "a[0]=-42.29440934724098,a[1]=5.594610216117472,a[2]=-0.1344605774892472,a[3]=0.0015448461146899649,a[4]=-8.253715806927624E-6,a[5]=1.7176546321558128E-8";
        String actual = p.toString();

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hyperbolic equations in general fit this data
well. My personal recommendation is to use

"Simple Equation 21"

http://zunzun.com/Equation/2/Simple/Simple%20Equation%2021/

instead of a polynomial.  But if what you have works, there is no particular reason to change it.

James Phillips
zunzun@zunzun.com